# Is windows still running in the background?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, security

Running 13.04 on a dual boot, Is windows 7 still live and hackable from the outside world? I put 13.04 on a separate 'drive'

Comment: please could you mark this question as answered, as this question is technically 'unanswered' at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You don't have Windows still running. You have booted an entirely separate Operating System.

Comment: If you put your Windows 7 to hibernate, then you won't be able to open your Windows 7 folder within Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it hasn't loaded the operating system. Until you start Windows manually, Windows is just a collection of files - so the files are hackable in the same way that your Ubuntu files are hackable - but it's not running anywhere.

EDIT: Beaten to it by @ir-g

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not running anything from Windows when you boot to Ubuntu. It is just a pack of harmless files on a hard drive then.